# AirFlow DatabricksSubmitRunOperator does not take in notebook parameters

Tags: airflow, databricks, azure-databricks

I am trying to trigger a notebook from Airflow. The notebook has parameters defined as widgets and I am trying to pass values to it through the notebook_params parameter and though it triggers, when I look at the job submitted, parameters do not seem to be passed.

E.g. code

```
new_cluster = {'spark_version': '6.5.x-cpu-ml-scala2.11',
                        'node_type_id': 'Standard_DS3_v2',
                        'num_workers': 4
                        }

notebook_task = DatabricksSubmitRunOperator(task_id='notebook_task',
             json={'new_cluster': new_cluster,
                                'notebook_task': {
                                    'notebook_path': '/Users/abc@test.com/Demo',
                                    'notebook_parameters':'{"fromdate":"20200420","todate":"20200420", "datalakename":"exampledatalake", "dbname": "default", "filesystem":"refined" , "tablename":"ntcsegmentprediction", "modeloutputpath":"curated"}'
                                },
                            })
```

however, DatabricksRunNowOperator supports it, and it works

```
notebook_run = DatabricksRunNowOperator(task_id='notebook_task',
            job_id=24,
            notebook_params={"fromdate":"20200420","todate":"20200420", "datalakename":"exampledatalake", "dbname": "default", "filesystem":"refined" , "tablename":"ntcsegmentprediction", "modeloutputpath":"curated"}
        )
```

In the documentation and source code of DatabricksSubmitRunOperator in [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_modules/airflow/contrib/operators/databricks_operator.html)

it says it can take in a notebook_task. If it can, not sure why it can't take in parameters

What am I missing?

If more information is required, I can provide that as well.

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I have the same question

Comment: I had to use the DatabricksRunNowOperator. Created a Databricks job and called it using it. The parameters then got passed correctly. Not sure what is the problem with DatabricksSubmitRunOperator. You may also want to use the DatabricksRunNowOperator.

Comment: hey Saugat I am also trying to trigger the notebook from Airflow please guide how did you fixed the issue. Please suggest it would be greate help.

Comment: Please use the DatabricksRunNowOperator like I said and also provided an example below. Create a job and then pass the id and parameters of that job. again- the example is in the question itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `base_parameters` instead of `notebook_params`

https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#jobsnotebooktask

Answer (score 4):

To use it with the DatabricksSubmitRunOperator you need to add it as an extra argument in the json parameter: [ParamPair](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#jobsparampair)

```
notebook_task_params = {
    'new_cluster': cluster_def,
    'notebook_task': {
        'notebook_path': 'path',
        'base_parameters':{
            "param1": "**",
            "param2": "**"}            
    }   
}
notebook_task = DatabricksSubmitRunOperator(
    task_id='id***',
    dag=dag,
    trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ALL_DONE,
    json=notebook_task_params)
```

And then you can just use the dbutils.widgets.get to retrieve the value or set defaults.

```
param1 = getArgument("param1", "default")
param2 = getArgument("param2", "default")
```

getArgument > (DEPRECATED) Equivalent to get

Comment: I did the same if you look at my question. The problem was, I was using notebook_params instead of base_parameters , as Gustavo pointed out in his answer.